# Is it possible to avoid 'eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)' error on custom React Hook with useCallback?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, eslint

Take the following custom React Hook to interact with `IntersectionObserver`:

```js
import { useCallback, useRef, useState } from 'react';

type IntersectionObserverResult = [(node: Element | null) => void, IntersectionObserverEntry?];

function useIntersectionObserver(options: IntersectionObserverInit): IntersectionObserverResult {
    const intersectionObserver = useRef<IntersectionObserver>();

    const [entry, setEntry] = useState<IntersectionObserverEntry>();

    const ref = useCallback(
        (node) => {
            if (intersectionObserver.current) {
                console.log('[useInterSectionObserver] disconnect()');
                intersectionObserver.current.disconnect();
            }

            if (node) {
                intersectionObserver.current = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
                    console.log('[useInterSectionObserver] callback()');
                    console.log(entries[0]);

                    setEntry(entries[0]);
                }, options);

                console.log('[useInterSectionObserver] observe()');
                intersectionObserver.current.observe(node);
            }
        },
        [options.root, options.rootMargin, options.threshold]
    );

    return [ref, entry];
}

export { useIntersectionObserver };
```

ESLint is complaining about:

> React Hook useCallback has a missing dependency: 'options'. Either include it or remove the dependency array.

If I replace the dependencies array with `[options]`, ESLint no longer complains but there's now a much bigger problem, **a rendering infinite loop**.

What would be the right way to implement this custom React Hook without having the `eslint(react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)` error showing up?

Answer (score 1):

The fix to this is to destructure the properties you need from `options` and set them in the dependancy array. That way you don't need `options` and the hook only gets called when those three values change.

```
import { useCallback, useRef, useState } from 'react';

type IntersectionObserverResult = [(node: Element | null) => void, IntersectionObserverEntry?];

function useIntersectionObserver(options: IntersectionObserverInit): IntersectionObserverResult {
    const intersectionObserver = useRef<IntersectionObserver>();
    const [entry, setEntry] = useState<IntersectionObserverEntry>();
    const { root, rootMargin, threshold } = options;

    const ref = useCallback(
        (node) => {
            if (intersectionObserver.current) {
                console.log('[useInterSectionObserver] disconnect()');
                intersectionObserver.current.disconnect();
            }

            if (node) {
                intersectionObserver.current = new IntersectionObserver((entries) => {
                    console.log('[useInterSectionObserver] callback()');
                    console.log(entries[0]);

                    setEntry(entries[0]);
                }, options);

                console.log('[useInterSectionObserver] observe()');
                intersectionObserver.current.observe(node);
            }
        },
        [root, rootMargin, threshold]
    );

    return [ref, entry];
}

export { useIntersectionObserver };
```

Comment: That didn't work either, but your suggestion made me think and I solved it by destructing in the function arguments and also removed the `options` from the `IntersectionObserver` and constructed the object again.

Comment: @rfgamaral the other option is to memo the `options` object and pass that into the hook

Comment: @MattAft Can you provide a full example with that option for documentation purposes?

Comment: @rfgamaral posted an answer, let me know if that fixes it for you

Answer (score 1):

You should always provide all the necessary values in the dep array to prevent it from using the previous cached function with stale values. One option to fix your situation is to memo the `options` object so only a new one is being passed when it's values change instead of on every re-render:

```
// in parent
// this passes a new obj on every re-render
const [ref, entry] = useIntersectionObserver({ root, rootMargin, threshold }); 

// this will only pass a new obj if the deps change
const options = useMemo(() => ({ root, rootMargin, threshold }), [root, rootMargin, threshold]);
const [ref, entry] = useIntersectionObserver(options);
```

Comment: Got it. What are the pros/cons over the other solution?

Comment: it's not a huge difference in this case because your hooks is pretty lightweight. but lets say that object can have different values, all your hook will care about if a new obj was passed in or not which can be determined by the memo'd obj in the parent

Comment: Thank you. I guess both answers work for me use case. But I understand how they work slightly different :)